# SQL insert from variable amount of HTML check boxes

Tags: php, sql, pdo, foreach, insert

I have a user input with checkboxes. The number of checkboxes can vary in quantity because they are generated with a fetch. I would like to transfer the respective value per selected checkbox into a table and create a row for each selected checkbox. My problem is that with my current code only the value from the last checkbox is taken. Not sure how to implement a foreach here.

My code currently looks like this:

HTML Checkbox example **which can repeat from 1 to unlimited**. Name is always the same but *value* and *id* is changing:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" name="questionaire_id" id="100" value="100">
<label class="custom-control-label mb-3" for="100"> &nbsp; Some_Name - 100 </label>
```

PDO Query PHP

```
 if (isset($_POST['speichern'])) {

 $questionaire_id = $_POST['questionaire_id'];

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO audit_bundles(questionaire_id) VALUES (:questionaire_id)");
    $result = $statement->execute(array('questionaire_id' => $questionaire_id));
}
```

Comment: _"Name is always the same"_ - well there's your problem. names must be unique, otherwise, how will the server distinguish different checkboxes? Ids have nothing to do with submissions, only names and values.

Comment: Not sure that I understand correctly, but it sounds like you would be fable to use a classic for loop, but first fetch the current amount of checkboxes displayed, and then bind the value of the "count" variable to the result. This way the amount of iterations is always the same as the amount of checkboxes.

Comment: For checkboxes that have multiple instances you need to append `[]` to the end of the name. I.e. if you change the name to `questionaire_id[]` then the server will have an array of values stored in `$_POST['questionaire_id']` instead of the last value that was checked.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution which works for me. It is taking the value from a selected checkbox and is creating a row. Does not matter how many check boxes i have.

```html
if (isset($_POST['speichern'])) {

    $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO audit_bundles (questionaire_id) VALUES (?)");
    $statement->bindParam(1, $questionaire_id);

    foreach ($_POST['questionaire_id'] as &$value) {

    // insert row
    $questionaire_id = $value;
    $statement->execute();

    }
```